# Camera android API 13

Tags: android, camera

I want to check the camera parameters, I have still old phone and I'm using the library android.hardware.camera. I've got an error here, I didn't find any solution on the others sites:

`java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.arkadio.cameralight/com.example.arkadio.cameralight
Binary XML file line #16: Error inflating class uses-permission"`

My XML is here

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            tools:context=".MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:text="@string/hello_world"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

and my code:

http://pastebin.com/8H4YH2iM

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`uses-permission` belongs to **AndroidManifest.xml**, not to layout resource XML files.